# Enable 2540*1440 resolution on Ubuntu 22 over VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, ubuntu-gnome

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64 on a VM using VirtualBox 6.1 then I have install Guest Addition using ISO provide by virtualBox. My OS Host is Windows 10.

The definition of my ubuntu window is automatically adjusted as long as I don't exceed 1920*1080, beyond that the window becomes all black. It becomes normal again if I go back down below 1920*1080. So I can't put the window in full screen on my 2540*1440 screen.
If I select manualy the 2540*1440 resolution on the parameters, the problem is same.
If I set full screen using virtualbox option or just by stretching the window manually it's same.

The Ubuntu desktop is Gnome 42.4
I have two screens of different definition.

Comment: Host OS? Graphics?

Comment: I add the Host OS but what are you meaning by Graphics ?

Comment: I mean which graphics card/chip?

Comment: How much video RAM is allocated for the machine?

Comment: I have a Nvidia Geforce 1070

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.
Thanks to @Pilot6 who question me about how much video RAM was allocated for the machine, I try to increase it and now it's work well in full screen.
To change video RAM allocated to the machine, I went to VirtualBox, I selected my machine, click on configuration -> Display -> Screen.
Then I went from 16 MB of video memory to 64 MB.